# Fiddler4 in windows server 2012 provokes RestSharp Requests to be null

Tags: c#, neo4j, fiddler, restsharp, windows-server-2012

So I'm testing Neo4J in pure REST (no Neo4JClient) and I have this code:

```
       var client = new RestClient("http://url");

        string requestText = "{  \"query\" : \"start x  = node(1) match path = (x--IsFriendOf) return path, IsFriendOf.name\",  \"params\" : {  }}";

        var request = new RestRequest();

        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.Resource = "/foo/bar";
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", requestText.Length.ToString());
        request.AddHeader("Host", "ip:port");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic encoded64credentials");


        request.AddBody(requestText);



        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

If I do the RAW request in Fiddler itself, I get the desired result,

But if I do it in a console application in .Net 4.5, I see this:

[image]

I created a rule in my firewall to allow incoming/outgoing requests for the console executable, and I deactivated IE protected mode, but still, no luck.

Do anyone have some idea about this issue?

Comment: What do you get from .NET? You've stated what you see in Fiddler, but not what the code actually returns. An error, perhaps with an error code?

Comment: thanks buddy! I saw your message on meta and I will reply there, in here I can tell you that the code does not do anything, is like is making many attempts and after a threshold, you get empty string

Comment: just to add, actually you can see the problem right there in the picture, If I'm making an HTTP request to a particular URL, Fiddler intercepts the request and shows me that it is being tunneled because I never see the original web request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here.

The first thing to understand is that you're not actually seeing the request at all-- the request you're showing in this screenshot is IE downloading Compatibility View List information, not any request you've made yourself.

You should probably start by reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/14/fiddler-and-windows-8-metro-style-applications-https-and-private-network-capabilities.aspx to understand how Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 have changed and what you need to do to capture their traffic in a local loopback proxy.

Comment: thanks @EricLaw, I searched for decades looking for a blog that could describe the problem I was having, I knew it had to be something about the newest versions because I never had that problem before, Thank you very much again. Side note, Kinda cool to have the answer from the very creator of Fiddler indeed.

Comment: FWIW this answers my question because I didn't understand what was happening, but I still have a problem on the AppContainer utility, could you be so kind to help me out? here is the question (specific for fiddler4 issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740065/failed-to-get-appcontainer-info-unable-to-enumerate-appcontainer-is-the-window

Answer (score -1):

I can't believe what I'm writting, but apparently the error was produced by Fiddler itself, I will find out what are the inner mechanisms of Fiddler to interrupt my calls.

So if you are making an http request to a REST API that is not on port 80, and you are either using WireShark or Fiddler for example, the request never reaches the endpoint.

I don't know how to solve it, but I do know how to avoid it, and that is, close all traffic monitors on the server. In my case I had Wireshark and Fiddler4 opened to help me debug the http request content, but of course I could never realize what was happening because I was debugging with the tool that was provoking the error.

I'm using Fiddler4 in windows server 2012, with VS2012 and .Net Framework 4.5 if this is useful for anyone that has any hint on why that happens.