# Failed to get AppContainer info: Unable to enumerate AppContainer

Tags: fiddler, windows-server-2012

This issue came after @EricLaw explained me what was the problem when [I could not receive a response back from my REST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709484/fiddler4-in-windows-server-2012-provokes-restsharp-requests-to-be-null/13714466#13714466).

Essentially the request was just returning blank, then I found out that if Fiddler was not running,
the application works just fine.

As Eric explains there are [some security issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/14/fiddler-and-windows-8-metro-style-applications-https-and-private-network-capabilities.aspx) that I should consider when developing/debugging in Windows Server 2012.

I followed the instructions and installed [the suggested utility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx) but when I click in the AppContainer Loopback utility I get the following error: *Failed to get AppContainer info: Unable to enumerate AppContainer, Is the windows Firewall Service started?*

Of course, my Firewall Service is working just fine.

Additionally there is something I still don't understand, why my HTTP request works just fine whenever Fiddler is not running anyway?

Has anyone had this problem already?

PS: we need a new tag called fiddler4

Comment: Are you running the final RTM version of Windows Server 2012? Can you send me the build number from Winver.exe?

Comment: hey Eric, this is it, Version 6.2 Build 9200

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late to bring this up, but since I had a fix I though it might be helpful to others, too.
I used the utility described [here](http://mymemorysucks.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/issues-with-fiddler-on-windows-8-1-and-ie-11/) and although it did not fix the issue for me, it had a glowing hint, the Windows Firewall.

What fixed the issue for me was starting **Windows Firewall** service, which I had disabled previously.

Hope this might help.